# Fastest way of doing a 1 to 1 left join on tables with a 1 to many relationship (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables that have a 1 to many relationship, which I'm doing a 1:1 left join on. The query returns the correct results but it shows up in my slow query log (it takes up to 5s). Is there a better way to write this query?

```
select * from
tablea a left join tableb b 
  on a.tablea_id = b.tablea_id
  and b.tableb_id = (select max(tableb_id) from tableb b2 where b2.tablea_id = a.tablea_id)
```

i.e. I would like `TableA` left joined to the row in `TableB` with the largest `tableb_id`.

```
TableA
tablea_id
1
2

TableB
tableb_id, tablea_id, data
1, 1, x
2, 1, y

Expected Result
tablea_id, tableb_id, data
1, 2, y
2, null, null
```

TableA has an index on `tablea_id` and TableB has a composite index on `tablea_id,tableb_id`.

Explain Output

```
+----+--------------------+---------------+--------+-----------------+---------------+---------+----------------------+-------+-------------+
| id | select_type        | table         | type   | possible_keys   | key           | key_len | ref                  | rows  | Extra       |
+----+--------------------+---------------+--------+-----------------+---------------+---------+----------------------+-------+-------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | c             | index  | NULL            | department_id | 4       | NULL                 | 18966 | Using index |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | recent_cv_lut | eq_ref | PRIMARY,case_id | PRIMARY       | 4       | func                 |     1 |             |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | cases_visits  | ref    | case_id         | case_id       | 4       | abcd_records_v2.c.id |     2 | Using index |
+----+--------------------+---------------+--------+-----------------+---------------+---------+----------------------+-------+-------------+
```

Comment: How many rows we have in tablea and tableb? Can you also post the DDL of the tables?

Comment: @AntoanMilkov tablea has 20,000 records and tableb has 60,000 records. sorry, I can't post the ddl but all the mentioned id columns are integers

Comment: do you really need the nulls ? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Likely, that correlated subquery is getting executed for each row from tableb.

(Without the output from EXPLAIN, we're really just guessing as to whether appropriate indexes are available, and if MySQL is making use of them.)

It might be more efficient to use an inline view query, to get the maximum tableb_id value for each tablea_id in one shot, and then use a join operation. Something like this:

```
SELECT a.*
     , b.*
  FROM tablea a
  LEFT
  JOIN ( SELECT n.tablea_id
              , MAX(n.tableb_id) AS max_tableb_id
           FROM tableb n
          GROUP
             BY n.tablea_id
       ) m
    ON m.tablea_id = a.tablea_id
  LEFT
  JOIN tableb b
    ON b.tablea_id = m.tablea_id
   AND b.tableb_id = m.max_tableb_id
```

That's an alternative, but there's no guarantee that's going to be faster. It really depends, on a whole load of things that we don't have any information about. (Number of rows, cardinality, datatypes, available indexes, etc.)

---

**EDIT**

As an alternative, we could do the join between tablea and tableb in an inline view. This might improve performance. (Again, it really depends on a lot of things we don't have any information about.)

```
SELECT m.tablea_id
     , m.foo
     , b.*
  FROM ( SELECT a.tablea_id
              , a.foo
              , MAX(n.tableb_id) AS max_tableb_id
           FROM tablea a
           LEFT
           JOIN tableb n ON n.tablea_id = a.tablea_id
          GROUP
             BY a.tablea_id
       ) m
  LEFT
  JOIN tableb b
    ON b.tablea_id = m.tablea_id
   AND b.tableb_id = m.max_tableb_id
```

Comment: Other than using select * which I would not use in production code, this is the right approach I suspect.

Comment: This query returns a smaller number of rows. I wonder if the inner join excludes rows in tablea that don't have an entry in tableb? I tried changing the inner join to a left join but aborted the query after 20s

Comment: @FuzzyTree: yes, exactly. That's my bad, that should have been an outer join; I missed the LEFT keyword. (I will edit to add that.)

Comment: thanks, I ran this query a couple of times and it takes ~ 30s

Comment: @FuzzyTree: as I said, performance is going to depend on a lot of things. That inline view query will get turned into a derived table, and there's no indexes on that when the outer query runs. For best performance, we'd want an index on `tableb (tablea_id,tableb_id)`, for both the inline view query, and the join to tableb.

Comment: Your 2nd query seems to consistently run in about half the time than my current query. Thanks for your help